# Shortcode is not outputting all of the desired markup

Tags: php, shortcode

I'm having trouble getting my shortcode to output all of the markup - for some reason it's only outputting part of it.

I have the following function:

```
function shortcode_container($atts, $content = null) {

            $type = isset($atts['type']) ? $atts['type'] : '';
            $margintop = isset($atts['margintop']) ? $atts['margintop'] : '';
            $marginbottom = isset($atts['marginbottom']) ? $atts['marginbottom'] : '';

            $output = '';

            $output .= '<div class="container '.$type.'" style="margin-top:'.$margintop.'; margin-bottom:'.$marginbottom.'">';
            $output .= '<section>';
            $output .= '<div class="row">';
            $output .= apply_filters('the_content', $content);
            $output .= '</div>';
            $output .= '</section>';
            $output .= '</div>';

            return $output;

        }
```

I want to be able to write into the WP WYSIWYG:

```
[container]

Text

[/container]
```

So it'll output as:

```
<div class="container">
<section>
<div class="row">
 Text
</div>
</section>
</div>
```

The code currently only outputs the `<div class="container">` and nothing else, no `<section>` or `<div class="row">`.

My full functions.php file is [here](http://pastebin.com/Jjn52zKD).

Comment: @PieterGoosen Not a dupe, one is asking for how to get a space and not the &nbsp version of a space. This is asking how to get html to output the way I want it to. Yes I did forget part of it so it was unclear, but I fixed it. You guys are so quick to downvote.

Comment: Don't take downvotes personally - they're usually just a signal to others that a question might not be quite clear cut / easy to understand / might require clarification etc. Some people will reverse their downvotes into  if a question is changed to fix some of the problems.

Comment: It's much clearer now. I've looked over your code several times though and I can't see what's wrong... it looks like it should be doing what you want. Is there a cheeky syntax error in there somewhere that we're both not seeing?

Comment: I'm assuming this is in your theme's functions.php, what else is in there? Any chance you've defined the shortcode multiple times while trying to get it right?

Comment: Agree with Tim. There is a missing semicolon after `margin-bottom` but that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @cjbj I hope I don't get down voted for this, but if there's a solution in here I'll update my OP. Here is my `functions.php` file [http://pastebin.com/UPNdY6Jc] here, the shortcodes I have are at the bottom.

Comment: Also, adding the semicolon, it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: I used to use output buffer around shortcode's HTML and that always works. Start with `ob_start()`, and end with `return ob_get_clean()`. And in between, place plain HTML or sometimes dynamic value using PHP, that always worked for me.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam Do you mind showing me exactly how that works? My php skills are super basic. I've also linked my entire `functions.php` into my OP, I've seen the code I provided used on another site and it outputs the divs as it should. I don't know what's in my file that's breaking it.

Comment: @DarrenBachan provided as an answer. Have a look, and let me updated whether it works or not. Because it's not tested.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this code and it appears to be working. Though as others have stated you are missing a semicolon at the end of margin-bottom, which you may want to add to be semantically correct.

With that being said, to get the code to output exactly how you want when entered into the WYSIWYG, without additional p tags wrapping the Text, you should add a filter to replace the `<p>` tags like so:

```
/* Shortcode Content Filter */
if ( ! function_exists( 'the_content_filter' ) ) :
    function the_content_filter($content) {
        $block = join("|",array('container'));
        $rep = preg_replace("/(<p>)?\[($block)(\s[^\]]+)?\](<\/p>|<br \/>)?/","[$2$3]",$content);
        $rep = preg_replace("/(<p>)?\[\/($block)](<\/p>|<br \/>)?/","[/$2]",$rep);
        return $rep;
    }
    add_filter("the_content", "the_content_filter");
endif;
```

Otherwise, doing this in the editor:

```
[container]

Text

[/container]
```

This will be output:

```
<div class="container test" style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px"><section><div class="row"><p></p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>
</p></div></section></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I often do an output buffering, and that works for me. Let's take a look at this example. Not tested.

And, `esc_attr()` will take care of all sorts of escaping for bad user inputs.

```
<?php
/**
 * Container shortcode
 *
 * Outputs a container wrapping the content.
 * 
 * @param  array $atts     Array of shortcode attributes.
 * @param  string $content Content within a shortcode.
 * @return string          The formatted content.
 */
function wpse_228875_shortcode( $atts, $content ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
                'type'          => '',
                'margintop'     => '',
                'marginbottom'  => '',
            ), $atts, 'container' );

    $type           = isset($atts['type'])          ? $atts['type']         : '';
    $margintop      = isset($atts['margintop'])     ? $atts['margintop']    : '';
    $marginbottom   = isset($atts['marginbottom'])  ? $atts['marginbottom'] : '';

    //start output buffering
    ob_start();
    ?>

    <div class="container <?php echo esc_attr($type); ?>" style="margin-top:<?php echo esc_attr($margintop); ?>; margin-bottom:<?php echo esc_attr($marginbottom); ?>;">
        <section>
            <div class="row">
                <?php
                /**
                 * Using do_shortcode() will allow you
                 * to use another shortcode within the
                 * container shortcode.
                 */
                echo do_shortcode( apply_filters( 'the_content', $content ) );
                ?>
            </div> <!-- /.row -->
        </section>
    </div> <!-- /.container -->

    <?php
    //cleanup the buffering and return everything within
    return ob_get_clean();

}

add_shortcode( 'container', 'wpse_228875_shortcode', 10, 2 );
```

#### Footnote: What is output buffering?

> *Without output buffering (the default), your HTML is sent to the browser in pieces as PHP processes through your script. With output buffering, your HTML is stored in a variable and sent to the browser as one piece at the end of your script.*

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2832179/1743124